# Line breakpoint:AndroidFacebookConnectActivity

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - R cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Line breakpoint:AndroidFacebookConnectActivity [line: 45] - 
     onCreate(Bundle)
```

having problem at all id's of resources in the following code ,here i am added facebook sdk and trying to run a imported sample project but showing the above error

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
        btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
        btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
        btnShowAccessTokens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_access_tokens);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
```

Comment: Try to clean your project and build again.

Comment: Fix any errors in the /res folder which block the R.class from being build.

Comment: there is know problem in my xml file,u want to see?

Answer (score 0):

The LineBreakpoint message is not an error: It is a notification that you put a breakpoint there. The R cannot be resolved message means that you didn't declare that variable. You might want to do this:
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` at the top of your page.